# Sorting an ArrayList of objects using attributes of these objects (using streams)

Tags: java, object, oop, arraylist, stream

I'm trying to sort an Array of song objects using a stream, the problem is I am trying to sort the list of objects using an attribute of the objects -title- which is then changing the data type of the stream to string. I don't know how to stop this from happening, any advice?

```
public void sort(){

allSongs = allSongs.stream()
                    .map(song -> song.getArtist(cs))
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList(allSongs));


}

public String getArtist(CustomSong cs){

return cs.artist;
    
}
```

Comment: What is `cs` in the `sort()` method? Why is `getArtist` an instance method when it doesn't use the `Song` object?

Comment: cs is the custom song object with the attributes: title, artist, duration, rating, totalListens, explicit and genre. and for the get artist method should i just reference it without an object?

Comment: Yeah, assuming the `getArtist` method is a method of the `CustomSong` class, it should have no arguments and should simply do `return this.artist;`. You need to re-read the section about getter and setter methods in your Java learning material.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Stream` method

```
Stream<T> sorted​(Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

and provide an appropriate comparator.

Comment: thanks, where can i find more info about this as i am not really familiar with comparators.

Comment: Use your favorite search engine to look for "java tutorial comparator".  There are several good explanations.  In future, please do some research before posting a question.

Comment: thanks for the help and fair enough ill do more research next time